# Why firebase.initializeApp return a FirebaseError: "projectId" not provided" with import/export syntaxe?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, node-modules, es6-modules

I dowloaded a correction folder for ecomerce project.
This is the error in console after the 'npm start' command:[image]
The problem can't come from the firebase object congig because I checked many time, I create a new one that I tried in another project olready in line and it works well.
I tried everything. I looked for everywhere in internet. I didn't find the solution who works for me.
I think the problem come from import/import syntaxe.
if anyone could try to make this project work and tell me what's wrong that would be great:
https://github.com/HALLneufmilles/ecom_2-0

here is a part of my server.js file:

```
import express from "express";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, doc, collection, setDoc, getDoc, updateDoc, getDocs, query, where, deleteDoc, limit } from "firebase/firestore";
import stripe from "stripe";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  type: "service_account",
  project_id: "ecom-website-ef3e5",
  private_key_id: "fcb20266224adb06a42e19754aa76029863492c4",
  private_key: "........................",
  client_email: "................gserviceaccount.com",
  client_id: "1..................0",
  auth_uri: "https....................th2/auth",
  token_uri: "https://o.......................oken",
  auth_provider_x509_cert_url: "htt.....................rviceaccount.com",
  universe_domain: "go.......com",
};
// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

// init server
const app = express();

// middlewares
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json()); // enables form sharing

// aws
import aws from "aws-sdk";
import "dotenv/config";

// aws setup
const region = "ap-south-1";
const bucketName = "ecom-website-4";
const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY;
const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY;

aws.config.update({
  region,
  accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey,
});

// init s3
const s3 = new aws.S3();

// generate image url
async function generateURL() {
  let date = new Date();

  const imageName = `${date.getTime()}.jpeg`;

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: imageName,
    Expires: 300, // 300 ms
    ContentType: "image/jpeg",
  };

  const uploadURL = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise("putObject", params);
  return uploadURL;
}

app.get("/s3url", (req, res) => {
  generateURL().then((url) => res.json(url));
});

// routes
// home route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("index.html", { root: "public" });
});

// signup
app.get("/signup", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("signup.html", { root: "public" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The config keys are incorrect, it should be `projectId` vs `project_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use a service account to initialize the Firebase client SDK.  That won't ever work.  You need to use the configuration object provided by the Firebase console for the **client SDK only**.  It looks like this:

```
  {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
```

Service accounts are used to initialize the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), which is for backends only. They require the service account for privileged operations, which are not things you should ever be doing in your client app.  If you are writing a nodejs program, you probably want to use the Firebase Admin SDK instead of the client SDK as you are now.